# Combining LIKE and IN for Ebean

Tags: playframework, orm, ebean

Given a List of words and a fruit class, lets say:

```
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("App", "banan", "mang", "kiwi"));
```

LIKE would go like this but only one at a time, which doesn't tally with IN:

```
Fruits.find.where().like('name', wordList.get(0)).findList();
```

IN would go like this:

```
List<Fruit> matchedFruitList = Fruit.find.where().in("name", wordList).findList();
```

Now what I need is to do a LIKE operation combined with IN operation.

Is there a way to do this with Ebean ORM???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to use `OR` condition and do LIKE for each of the words.

```
ExpressionList<Fruit> scope = Fruit.find.where();

for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
    scope = scope.or().like("name", "%" + wordList.get(i) + "%");
}

List<Fruit> matchedFruitList = scope.findList();
```

It is fine when the `wordList` is not very large. If it is, I think you should use RawSql and database specific syntax to perform the query.

Comment: but the like is only gonna work for first element, i wanted to do a LIKE operation IN all the elements of the wordlist.